# Rails 4 OpenId Example

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, openid

I'm having a very hard time finding any kind of example on the net of an OpenId implementation running in Rails 4.

I would eventually like to build my own OpenId Identity server, but in the meantime, I would settle for just being able to consume OpenId authentication in a Rails 4 app.

There are a ton of implementations that run in Rails 3, but I can't find a single one for Rails 4.

So, has anyone ever come across a good walkthrough, or tutorial on how to utilize OpenId authentication in a Rails 4 app ?

Thank you for your time.